# Enable "Filter on type" by default

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I enable this feature all the time, it always resets:

[image]

Comment: From version 1.63.0 the setting "Filter on type" is remembered.

Start typing -> Select "Enable Filter on Type" -> Hit Esc -> Start typing again - setting "Enable Filter on Type" is remembered.

Comment: "workbench.list.keyboardNavigation": "filter"

Comment: Thanks @niciki, that workbench setting worked. Without it it doesn't work and is remembered after restart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable it all the time, by the following entry in settings.json:

```
"workbench.list.keyboardNavigation": "filter"
```